# What is the difference in meaning of 'monstrousness/monstrous' and 'monstrosity'?

Tags: meaning, connotation

I wondered if someone could tell me what the difference in meaning is of 'monstrousness' and 'monstrosity'? I looked up the definitions and this is what I found:

> **monstrous**
>
> 1.
>   frightful or hideous, especially in appearance; extremely ugly.
>
> 2.
>   shocking or revolting; outrageous
>
> **monstrosity**
>
> 1.
>   the state or character of being monstrous.
>
> 2.
>   a monster or something monstrous.

Can someone please give me more information regarding the denotations and connotations of these two terms?

Answer (score 0):

"Monstrous" is an adjective, and "Monstrosity" is a noun.

> - What a monstrous person!
> - What a monstrosity(bad person)!

There are, of course, differences in uses; similarly to "beautiful>beauty".

Other than that, "monstrous" is quite often used as a stronger adjective of "very large".

> Look at that building! It's monstrous!

Likewise, you can say something very large is a "monstrosity", but is has bad connotations.

> Look at that building! What a monstrosity!

It conveys that the building is big and ugly/dirty, etc.

Comment: Do you know the difference between 'monstrousness' and 'monstrosity'?

Comment: I mean, are 'monstrousness' and 'monstrosity' interchangeable?

Comment: "Monstrousness" is a noun, but is most often used to describe "monstrosity" as a whole, as an abstract concept. Using "monstrousness" just to replace "monstrosity" sounds unidiomatic, but I think it is grammatically correct.